# pyspark - create Top3 groups and aggregate other groups/rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, aggregation

I would like to create a new dataFrame where column `type` will be the topX based on the *highest* `count`. 
There will be an *additional* type (*others*) that will be the *sum* of all the typeX for the same group `name`.

for the DF:

```
data = spark.createDataFrame([
      ("name1", "type1", 2), ("name1", "type2", 1), ("name1", "type3", 4), ("name1", "type3", 5), \
      ("name2", "type1", 6), ("name2", "type1", 7), ("name2", "type2", 8) \
    ],["name", "type", "cnt"])
    data.printSchema()
```

what is:

```
|name  |type|cnt|
|------|-----------
|name1 |typeA|  6|
|name1 |typeX|  5|
|name1 |typeW|  3|
|name1 |typeZ|  1|
|name2 |typeA|  7|
|name2 |typeB|  2|
| .... | ... |   |
```

The resulting Dataframe (for a Top 2) would be:
*Each name has top2 values + 'other' (3 groups)*

```
|name  |type|cnt|
|------|-----------
|name1 |typeA|  6|
|name1 |typeX|  5|
|name1 |other|  4|
|name2 |typeA|  7|
|name2 |typeB|  2|
|name2 |other|  0|
| .... | ... |   |
```

I am not sure how can I skip X rows for a certain group and then start aggregating the remaining rows.

Comment: Are there repeated types for each name? Your code doesn't seem to give the table you are showing.

Answer (score 2):

I tried using window functions along with rank of rows based on name and cnt,then filter first 2 ranks for each name and aggregate the others and finally union them.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
>>> data = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("name1", "type1", 2), ("name1", "type2", 1), ("name1", "type3", 4), ("name1", "type3", 5), \
  ("name2", "type1", 6), ("name2", "type1", 7), ("name2", "type2", 8) \
],["name", "type", "cnt"])
>>> data.show()
+-----+-----+---+
| name| type|cnt|
+-----+-----+---+
|name1|type1|  2|
|name1|type2|  1|
|name1|type3|  4|
|name1|type3|  5|
|name2|type1|  6|
|name2|type1|  7|
|name2|type2|  8|
+-----+-----+---+

>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import rank, col,lit
>>> window = Window.partitionBy(data['name']).orderBy(data['cnt'].desc())
>>> data1 = data.select('*', rank().over(window).alias('rank'))
>>> data1.show()
+-----+-----+---+----+
| name| type|cnt|rank|
+-----+-----+---+----+
|name1|type3|  5|   1|
|name1|type3|  4|   2|
|name1|type1|  2|   3|
|name1|type2|  1|   4|
|name2|type2|  8|   1|
|name2|type1|  7|   2|
|name2|type1|  6|   3|
+-----+-----+---+----+
>>> data2 = data1.filter(data1['rank'] > 2).groupby('name').sum('cnt').select('name',lit('other').alias('type'),col('sum(cnt)').alias('cnt'))
>>> data2.show()
+-----+-----+---+
| name| type|cnt|
+-----+-----+---+
|name1|other|  3|
|name2|other|  6|
+-----+-----+---+
>>> data1.filter(data1['rank'] <=2).select('name','type','cnt').union(data2).show()
+-----+-----+---+
| name| type|cnt|
+-----+-----+---+
|name1|type3|  5|
|name1|type3|  4|
|name2|type2|  8|
|name2|type1|  7|
|name1|other|  3|
|name2|other|  6|
+-----+-----+---+
```